# Saving unique array elements MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save a unique array of String elements using MongoDB but for some reason it allows me to save duplicates.

I am using mongoose. My code:

```
 schema = mongoose.Schema({
    "searchingId": { "type":  String,
        "unique": true,
        "index": true },
    "sharedTo" : {
        type: [String],
        unique: true,
        "trim":true
    }
}, {collection: 'myCollection'});
```

Basically the point is to keep a list of email addresses where the user had sent emails and to prevent the user from spamming them. But this schema will allow me to push any string to a `sharedTo` array and to `.save()` it no matter whether the duplicates exist. How to prevent this from happening?

EDIT: 
Lahar's answer does help with my question but not entierly. I would like to prevent user from adding emails  if there is at *least one* duplicate. So basically $addToSet will help with uniqueness but not with my question.

Comment: Can you give examples of the kind of duplicate records you're trying to prevent, which it is allowing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like I had found the solution myself but thanks to the Lahar Shah answer for pointing me in the right direction. Instead of using

```
Model.update(conditions, doc, [options], [callback])
```

I did

- fetching the object
- Added each of emails to my *sharedTo* attribute while checking for duplicates.
- saving the object if no duplicates

Code:

```
var  length = emails.length;
for( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    var saved = doc.sharedTo.addToSet(emails[i]).length;
    if (saved != 1) {
        //status 409 - You have already sent email to user emails[i]
        return;
    }
}

doc[0].save(function(fail, success) {
    if(fail) {
        //error
    } else {
        //success return 200
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $addToSet instead of $push to add email in "sharedTo" array. 
That won't add duplicate element(email in your case).

By providing unique:true to whole array field won't check uniqueness of array element.

Please check [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) documentation.

Comment: This is almost the answer I need. The problem is that I want to throw an error if there is a duplicate and to return 409 conflict. Is that even possible?

Comment: So when you run that update it returns writeResult object with count nMatched, nUpserted, nModified. 
nModified will tell you how many documents are modified.

Comment: Yes but it saves the object to the database, so technically i would have to rollback to previous version if  the modified is less than length of input? That sounds like dirty and wrong solution, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet where you need to validate ? That will give better idea where and how you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your own static function that will run from the schema class to do this for every email entered

```
UserSchema.statics.findUseremail = function(useremail, suffix,
callback) {

var _this = this;
var possibleuseremail = useremail + (suffix || '');
_this.findOne({
    useremail: possibleuseremail
    }, function(err, userem) {
    if (!err) {
        if (!userem) {
            callback(findUseremail);
        } else {
        return _this.findUseremail(useremail, (suffix || 0) +
        1, callback);
        }
    } else {
    callback(null);
    }
});
};
```